# How to redirect using ajax in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ajax, html, html5-appcache

I want to redirect a user on specific page using ajax call in angularjs. I am able to redirect using below mentioned code but when i again want to redirect user to root page i am unable to do so as the value of $window.location.href+ 'getTechnicianWorkOrder/'+woId is persisting as is:

```
  $scope.getTechnicianWorkOrderFormURL = function(woId){ 
       return $window.location.href + 'getTechnicianWorkOrder/'+woId;   
     };
```

Another place where i want to redirect to root page:

```
 $scope.getAssignedListURL = function(){     
    return $window.location.href;
};
```

Note: i want to make this redirection work even in offline mode of HTML5 cache-manifest.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#path) service.

`$location.path('/');`

Comment: where to use it? Can u edit my code sample above and show  where to use it?

Comment: I guess you have an ng-click on your app or some ajax callback that invokes the function to go back to the root page, in that function put the code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @prashant-palikhe is the right one, `$location.path('/');` is the route to your root path. just use the dependency of `$location` to your `controller` like this:

```
yourapp.controller('YourController', ['$location', function($location) {
    ...
}
```

I always use the [ui.router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for my routes and in there you can add `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')` for fallback in any unknown `state` or `route`.

In some cases you can add something like this in your states:

```
resolve : {
    dataObj : ['$http', function($http) {
        return $http({method : 'GET', url : '/your/ajax/endpoint'})
    ;}],
},
onEnter : ['dataObj', '$state', function(dataObj, $state) {
    // dataObj is your ajax response object. Based on this you can redirect to a certain state of needed
    $state.go('default');
}]
```

`resolve` is data that preloads data `onEnter` is called before entering the state. This can be used as some sort of middleware.